# Asp.Net MVC - Access to Postgresql with Entity Framework + Npgsql.Entityframework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC application which uses a PostgreSql database. Model classes are in a different class library. For access to database i'm using Entity Framework + Npgsql.Entityframework from Nuget in the class library. Also i added same links to main project. Configuration settings are in web.config of main project:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" 
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
             requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="Npgsql" 
                  type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NpgsqlContext" 
         providerName="Npgsql" 
         connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;User Id=BaseId;Password=BasePass;Port=5432;Database=Base;" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" 
             invariant="Npgsql"
             support="FF" 
             description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql"
             type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

I created database and some tables in pgAdmin. To access to base and tables i use classes (example):
    public class NpgsqlContext : DbContext
        {
            public NpgsqlContext(): base(nameOrConnectionString: "NpgsqlContext") 
            {
            }

```
        public DbSet<BaseArticle> BaseArticles { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("ARTICLE", Schema = "public")]
    public class BaseArticle
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("ID")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("DATETIME")]
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

        [Column("TITLE")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Column("BODY")]
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
```

NpgsqlContext object is created normally and has right connectionn string (`PORT=5432;KRBSRVNAME=name;TIMEOUT=15;POOLING=True;MINPOOLSIZE=1;MAXPOOLSIZE=20;COMMANDTIMEOUT=20;COMPATIBLE=2.2.7.0;HOST=127.0.0.1;USER ID=BasePass;PASSWORD=BasePass;DATABASE=Base`), but didn't see any records in datatable in base - DbSet BaseArticle's count equals 0. Meanwhile records are there. Where can i have an error?

And also - in ASP.NET MVC generally impossible to achieve loose coupling between the parts of the application? For example - i created ASP.NET MVC application and carried out classes of access to a database in separate libraries. But i had to indicate links to the packages from Nuget in the main project. How could I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the solution of my problem i needed to open connection to base in constructor of context:

```
this.Database.Connection.Open();
```